# How to shuffle the first n elements in array

Tags: arrays, ruby

Let:

```
example = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I want to shuffle its first five elements. Other elements have to remain under the same index, e.g.:

```
[2,4,1,3,5,6,7,8,9]
[3,1,4,5,2,6,7,8,9]
# etc
```

I've tried `example.shuffle`, but it shuffles all elements.

Comment: what code have you tried so far for solving this ?

Comment: Tried `example.shuffle`. But it shuffles all elements. And also `example.shuffle[0..4]`. It results array of shuffled elements `[2,3,1,5,4]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can *get* the first 5 elements via [`[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D):

```
example[0, 5]
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Likewise, you can *set* the first 5 element via [`[]=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D):

```
example[0, 5] = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
#=> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

example
#=> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

So to `shuffle` the first 5 elements, you could use:

```
example[0, 5] = example[0, 5].shuffle
#=> [3, 2, 1, 4, 5]

example
#=> [3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Note that `example[0, 5].shuffle!` would *not* work because `Array#[]` returns a new array instead of a reference to a subarray (there's no such thing in Ruby).

Comment: A small point: the OP has not made it clear whether the array is to be mutated, but the reference to `example.shuffle` may suggest that it is not to be mutated.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 
a[0..4].shuffle + a[5..-1]
```

Comment: Or `a[0...5]` to make it a little more obvious.

Answer (score 2):

```
example = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

example.first(5).shuffle + example.last(4)
```

will return the array you need, although it might not be the most elegant solution

**EDIT**

As @Stefan commented, you can use `drop` so you don't have to calculate the length of the remaining array:

```
example.first(5).shuffle + example.drop(5)
```

Comment: You can use `drop(5)` instead of `last(4)`, so you don't have to calculate the difference.

Comment: You appear to agree with @Stefan that your answer would be improved by using `drop` rather than `last`. If so (and I think most Rubiests would agree), your answer would be cleaner if you simply made that change and omitted  your “EDIT” (so no mention would be made of `last`). Moreover, you thanked Stefan in a comment (the place to do that, IMO), so there’s no need to do that in your answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

A few more fun ways: (All non destructive)

```
 a =[*1..9]

 a.each_slice(5).to_a.tap do |f| 
   f.first.shuffle!
 end.reduce(:+)

 a.reduce([]) do |memo,n|
   (memo << n).size == 5 ? memo.shuffle : memo
 end

 a.partition.with_index do |_,i| 
   i < 5 
 end.inject { |memo,p| memo.shuffle.concat(p) }

 a.values_at(*[*0..4].shuffle).push(*a.drop(5))
```

I also really like this one but only if all the elements are guaranteed unique

```
 a.take(5).shuffle | a
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm late, but my two cents.
This is destructive.

```
example.shift(5).shuffle + example
```

Comment: you could make it "less destructive" via `example.unshift(*example.shift(5).shuffle)`. This will still mutate `example` but `example` will still contain all the original elements. Not dissimilar from the elected answer

Comment: @engineersmnky, great! I was looking for a splat solution like yours but I was not able: you would get my UP. Destructive: I mean that changes the original array: `example = example.shift(5).shuffle + example`. While  `example.first(5).shuffle + example.last(4)` is not.